# Howto be notified of an error from QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow?

Tags: c++, qt, oauth-2.0

I am using [QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qoauth2authorizationcodeflow.html) to perform OIDC authentication.
I can connect to the signal [QAbstractOAuth::granted()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractoauth.html#granted) and be notified when it worked with success. Fine.

My problem is: how to be notified when something **wrong** happened?

I tried to connect to the [QAbstractOAuth2::error()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractoauth2.html#error) signal but I am not notified.
I used:

```
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(error(const QString &, const QString &, const QUrl &)), this, SLOT(catchAll()));
```

In the application console I see the error reported by the server:

```
qt.networkauth.replyhandler: Error transferring https://idp.safenetid.com/auth/realms/2H31DFOIEQ-STA/protocol/openid-connect/token - server replied: Fake Bad request
```

So Qt detected the problem. It looks like the probem is detected in [QHttpThreadDelegate::finishedSlot()](https://sources.debian.org/src/qtbase-opensource-src/5.15.2+dfsg-15/src/network/access/qhttpthreaddelegate.cpp/?hl=542#L542):

```
if (httpReply->statusCode() >= 400) {
        // it's an error reply
        QString msg = QLatin1String(QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("QNetworkReply",
                                                      "Error transferring %1 - server replied: %2"));
        msg = msg.arg(httpRequest.url().toString(), httpReply->reasonPhrase());
        emit error(statusCodeFromHttp(httpReply->statusCode(), httpRequest.url()), msg);
    }
```

An `error()` signal is emitted. But it is catched by Qt itself and not reported upstream to the application?

Note:
Sometimes the server I use replies with an HTTP error code 400 and message "User not found".
Here I faked the problem using [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) to be able to reproduce the issue easily.

PS: I think it is a missing feature in Qt. So I created an issue for [QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::requestAccessToken()](https://github.com/qt/qtnetworkauth/blob/dev/src/oauth/qoauth2authorizationcodeflow.cpp#L391) at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-102279

Answer (score 0):

You can get notified by implementing your own `OAuthHttpServerReplyHandler`.
This handler has to be set to your `QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow` by using its `setReplyHandler(_)`.

The `OAuthHttpServerReplyHandler` has to override the `void networkReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)` which will get called by QT.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: Connect to `QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizationCallbackReceived`,
and write your own handler.**

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/qt/qtnetworkauth/blob/ec27270101077b629fac3c0e7aec7dbe9ff0c668/src/oauth/qoauth2authorizationcodeflow.cpp#L78) the problem seems to be that only one of these case statements will actually emit the `error` signal. They all return without a `Q_EMIT error(...)` call.

```cpp
void QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlowPrivate::_q_handleCallback(const QVariantMap &data)
{
    Q_Q(QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow);
    using Key = QAbstractOAuth2Private::OAuth2KeyString;

    if (status != QAbstractOAuth::Status::NotAuthenticated) {
        qCWarning(loggingCategory, "Unexpected call");
        return;
    }

    Q_ASSERT(!state.isEmpty());

    const QString error = data.value(Key::error).toString();
    const QString code = data.value(Key::code).toString();
    const QString receivedState = data.value(Key::state).toString();
    if (error.size()) {
        const QString uri = data.value(Key::errorUri).toString();
        const QString description = data.value(Key::errorDescription).toString();
        qCWarning(loggingCategory, "AuthenticationError: %s(%s): %s",
                 qPrintable(error), qPrintable(uri), qPrintable(description));
        Q_EMIT q->error(error, description, uri);
        return;
    }
    if (code.isEmpty()) {
        qCWarning(loggingCategory, "AuthenticationError: Code not received");
        return;
    }
    if (receivedState.isEmpty()) {
        qCWarning(loggingCategory, "State not received");
        return;
    }
    if (state != receivedState) {
        qCWarning(loggingCategory, "State mismatch");
        return;
    }

    setStatus(QAbstractOAuth::Status::TemporaryCredentialsReceived);

    QVariantMap copy(data);
    copy.remove(Key::code);
    extraTokens = copy;
    q->requestAccessToken(code);
}
```

But there also seems to be a misunderstanding as to what the `error` signal is for; Based on the parameters in its declaration,

```
void QAbstractOAuth2::error(const QString &error, const QString &errorDescription, const QUrl &uri)
```

The error signal is *specifically* for the HTTP 400 "Bad Request" response as described in [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2), rather than as a signal for all errors, which is why it won't emit signal on (client-side) errors for things like `state mismatch` (which could be a quite serious error).

If you are still keen on propagating the `error` signal, however, you can connect to the `&QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizationCallbackReceived` signal as the [private class does](https://github.com/qt/qtnetworkauth/blob/ec27270101077b629fac3c0e7aec7dbe9ff0c668/src/oauth/qoauth2authorizationcodeflow.cpp#L414), then emit the `error` signal. It takes a bit of creativity because members in the code flow private class are not available, but it can be done.

For example, if you want to propagate error on a state mismatch, that might look like this:

```
{
   static QString last_state;
   QObject::connect(
      &oauth2, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::stateChanged,
      [&](const QString& state) {
         last_state = state;
      });
   QObject::connect(
      &oauth2, QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizationCallbackReceived,
      [&](const QVariantMap& data) {
         const QString state = data.value("state").toString();

         if(last_state != state) {
             Q_EMIT oauth2.error(
                 "The state in request does not match the state in reply!",                      
                 "State Mismatch!",
                 QUrl());
         }
       });
}
```

Since this is an abuse of the `error` function, however, I would suggest putting all this in a different object or class; One that would have `stateUpdated` and `onCallbackReceived` slots and be capable of emitting a `stateMismatch` signal, maybe.